# Пустота между блоками. Что делать в таком случае?

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка

Скриншот:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8HAu.png

JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/3PJQa/1/

```css
body {
    background-color: #eef1f4;
}
.row {
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}
.row:before, .row:after {
    display: table;
    content:" ";
}
.row:after {
    clear: both;
}
.row:before, .row:after {
    display: table;
    content:" ";
}
.row:after {
    clear: both;
}
.col-xs-1, .col-xs-2, .col-xs-3, .col-xs-4, .col-xs-5, .col-xs-6, .col-xs-7, .col-xs-8, .col-xs-9, .col-xs-10, .col-xs-11, .col-xs-12, .col-sm-1, .col-sm-2, .col-sm-3, .col-sm-4, .col-sm-5, .col-sm-6, .col-sm-7, .col-sm-8, .col-sm-9, .col-sm-10, .col-sm-11, .col-sm-12, .col-md-1, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12, .col-lg-1, .col-lg-2, .col-lg-3, .col-lg-4, .col-lg-5, .col-lg-6, .col-lg-7, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-9, .col-lg-10, .col-lg-11, .col-lg-12 {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
.col-xs-1, .col-xs-2, .col-xs-3, .col-xs-4, .col-xs-5, .col-xs-6, .col-xs-7, .col-xs-8, .col-xs-9, .col-xs-10, .col-xs-11 {
    float: left;
}
.col-xs-1 {
    width: 8.333333333333332%;
}
.col-xs-2 {
    width: 16.666666666666664%;
}
.col-xs-3 {
    width: 25%;
}
.col-xs-4 {
    width: 33.33333333333333%;
}
.col-xs-5 {
    width: 41.66666666666667%;
}
.col-xs-6 {
    width: 50%;
}
.col-xs-7 {
    width: 58.333333333333336%;
}
.col-xs-8 {
    width: 66.66666666666666%;
}
.col-xs-9 {
    width: 75%;
}
.col-xs-10 {
    width: 83.33333333333334%;
}
.col-xs-11 {
    width: 91.66666666666666%;
}
.col-xs-12 {
    width: 100%;
}
.news-div {
    margin: 20px 20px 0px 0;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: #fafafa;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="news-div col-xs-4">
         <h3>Test!</h3>

        <p>Астрономы, работающие с радиотелескопом ALMA, получили детальные изображения туманности PGC 3074547, она же туманность Бумеранг. В этой предпланетной туманности, которая также известна в качестве самого холодного места Вселенной, обнаружился «призрак», облако газа необычной формы. Подробности со ссылкой на материалы Национальной Радиоастрономической обсерватории США и публикацию (препринт доступен на arxiv.org) ученых в журнале Astrophysical Journal приводит Phys.org.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="news-div col-xs-4">
         <h3>Test!</h3>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius, mollitia, architecto, accusantium provident omnis possimus placeat laboriosam voluptas recusandae id quisquam culpa doloribus. Vitae, mollitia, ex iure asperiores reiciendis sapiente.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="news-div col-xs-4">
         <h3>Test!</h3>

        <p>Астрономы, работающие с радиотелескопом ALMA, получили детальные изображения туманности PGC 3074547, она же туманность Бумеранг. В этой предпланетной туманности, которая также известна в качестве самого холодного места Вселенной, обнаружился «призрак», облако газа необычной формы. Подробности со ссылкой на материалы Национальной Радиоастрономической обсерватории США и публикацию (препринт доступен на arxiv.org) ученых в журнале Astrophysical Journal приводит Phys.org.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="news-div col-xs-4">
         <h3>Test!</h3>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius, mollitia, architecto, accusantium provident omnis possimus placeat laboriosam voluptas recusandae id quisquam culpa doloribus. Vitae, mollitia, ex iure asperiores reiciendis sapiente.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="news-div col-xs-4">
         <h3>Test!</h3>

        <p>Астрономы, работающие с радиотелескопом ALMA, получили детальные изображения туманности PGC 3074547, она же туманность Бумеранг. В этой предпланетной туманности, которая также известна в качестве самого холодного места Вселенной, обнаружился «призрак», облако газа необычной формы. Подробности со ссылкой на материалы Национальной Радиоастрономической обсерватории США и публикацию (препринт доступен на arxiv.org) ученых в журнале Astrophysical Journal приводит Phys.org.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: это ни о чем не говорит. кидайте код на http://jsfiddle.net/ или покажите сайт

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3PJQa/1/

Comment: делать не ряды, а колонки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уже писала как-то. Плагин [Masorny](http://masonry.desandro.com/) должен помочь.